# Pattern backreference to an optional capturing subexpression

Tags: regex, bash, backreference

In an attempt to use Bash's built-in regular expression matching to parse the following types of strings, which are to be converted to Perl substitution expressions (quotes are not part of data)

```
'~#A#B#'
#^ ^ ^-- Replacement string.
#| +---- Pattern string.
#+------ Regular expression indicator (no need to escape strings A and B),
#        which is only allowed if strings A and B are surrounded with ##.
#        Strings A and B may not contain #, but are allowed to have ~.

'#A#B#'
#^------ When regex indicator is missing, strings A and B will be escaped.

'A#B'
#        Simplified form of '#A#B#', i. e. without the enclosing ##.
#        Still none of the strings A and B is allowed to contain # at any position,
#        but can have ~, so leading ~ should be treated as part of string A.
```

I tried the following pattern (again, without quotes):

```
'^((~)?(#))?([^#]+)#([^#]+)\3$'
```

That is, it declares the leading `~#` optional (and `~` in it even more optional), then captures parts `A` and `B`, and requires the trailing `#` to be present only if it was present in the leader. The leading `#` is captured for backreference matching only — it is not needed elsewhere, while `~` is captured to be inspected by script afterwards.

However, that pattern only works as expected with the most complete types of input data:

```
'~#A#B#'
'#A#B#'
```

but not for

```
'A#B'
```

I. e., whenever the leading part is missing, `\3` fails to match. But if `\3` is replaced with `.*`, the match succeeds and it can be seen that `${BASH_REMATCH[3]}` is an empty string. This is something that I do not understand, provided that unset variables are treated as empty strings in Bash. **How do I match a backreference with optional content then?**

As a workaround, I could write an alternative pattern

```
'^(~?)#([^#]+)#([^#]+)#$|^([^#]+)#([^#]+)$'
```

but it results in distinct capture groups for each possible case, which makes the code less intuitive.

Important note. As @anubhava mentioned in his comment, **backreference matching may not be available in some Bash builds** (perhaps it is a matter of build options rather than of version number, or even of some external library). This question is of course targeted at those Bash environments that support such functionality.

Comment: Try `'^(~?#?)([^#]+)#([^#]+)\1$'`, or perhaps, if `~` does not have to be checked for presence both at the start and end of the string, try `^~?(#?)([^#]+)#([^#]+)\1$`

Comment: Sorry for being not so clear, but the leading `~` can only be present if `#` is there — they are not two independent parts.

Comment: Try [`^(~?(#?))([^#]+)#([^#]+)\2$`](https://regex101.com/r/sF1qY1/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, you still did not get it: `#` in the front cannot be missing if `~` is already there, so your expression does not fit my task even if it works for some input. That is, it splits `~A#B` to `('~' 'A' 'B')` instead of ('~A' 'B') — when no hashes embrace the strings, leading `~` has no special meaning and must be considered a part of first string.

Comment: Sorry, the question is really unclear. Just note that capture group content once captured is treated as a single atom, and the backreference will point to that text. Its purpose is to match exactly what was matched. Now, you cannot use lookarounds in Bash regex, only in Perl one, so there is no way to restrict the `~` at the beginning, nor use a branch reset. I cannot see any workaround here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, I overestimated my descriptive skills, because the task seemed so easy to me, and I really thought my initial regex should do the trick (without any use of look-arounds and conditionals) — and I still do not understand why it does not, as well as option 1 proposed by *Rawing* (changing optionality with empty alternative), despite `$BASH_REMATCH` contents being populated as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to deal with this problem:

1. Instead of making the group optional (in other words, allowing it to not match at all), make it mandatory but match the empty string. In other words, change constructs like `(#)?` to `(#?)`.
2. Use a conditional to match the backreference `\3` only if group 3 matched. To do this, change `\3` to `(?(3)#|)`.

Generally, the first option is preferable because of its better readability. Also, bash's regular expressions don't seem to support conditional constructs, so we need to make option 1 work. This is difficult because of the additional condition that `~` is only allowed if `#` is also present. If bash supported lookaheads, we could do something like `((~)(?:#))?(#?)`. But since it doesn't, we need to get creative. I've come up with the following pattern:

```
^((~(#))|(#?))([^#]+)#([^#]+)(\3|\4)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fA5dO2/2).

The idea is to make use of the alternation operator `|` to handle two different cases: Either the text starts with `~#`, or it doesn't. `((~(#))|(#?))` captures `~#` in group 2 and `#` in group 3 if possible, but if there's no `~` then it just captures `#` (if present) in group 4. Then we can use `(\3|\4)` at the end to match the closing `#`, if there was an opening one (remember, group 3 captured `#` if the text started with `~#`, and group 4 captured `#` or the empty string if the text did *not* start with `~#`).

Comment: Good point on option 1 (`^((~)?(#)|)([^#]+)#([^#]+)\3$`), but unfortunately it has the same effect — when the alternate route is taken, `\3` does not match any more, although `${BASH_REMATCH[*]}` looks as expected. Conditional matching, however, does not seem to be working — is it supported in Bash?

Comment: Антон, `\3` refers to `(#)` only. You need to use `\1`

Comment: @AntonSamsonov It should be `(#?)`, not `(#)|`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and @Rawing, please, see the updated description: `#` at the beginning and the end can only be optional if no `~` is specified at the beginning (also, `~` is not allowed at the end). So, when I try to match `\3` against `#` or nothing, I really mean it. Moreover, to be clear, `#` is only captured for backreference matching — it is not needed elsewhere, while `~` is captured to be checked by further code.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov Answer updated. As always, bash sure didn't make this easy.

Comment: Wow, that is indeed *creative*, and it really works — including with original `[^#]` restriction on strings A and B contents. And, although `~` is not captured by itself but with accompanying `#`, there is no need for yet another capture group, because checking the presense of `~` can be accomplished by consulting whether `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` is non-empty.

Comment: You cannot use back reference in the regex using BASH's `=~` operator. Try `[[ 'A-A' =~ ^(A)-\1$ ]]`

Comment: @anubhava Yes, actually we can, at least in Bash 4.x (and not in Bash 2.x). As for your example, there is probably some escaping problem: if you assign both the string and the pattern to variables beforehead (also putting the pattern in single quotes) and then expand them in test operator (optionally putting the string in double quotes), the match succeeds as expected.

Comment: I have BASH `4.3.42(1)-release` and still it is not available. `s='A-A'; re='^(A)-\1$'; [[ $s =~ $re ]]` always fails.

Comment: @anubhava Indeed, while my primary 4.2.47(1)-release (openSUSE 42.1) works, as well as 4.3.11(1)-release (Ubuntu 14.04) of my colleague, running the very same script in 4.3.42(4)-release (Cygwin 2.4) leads to mismatch. Perhaps it is influenced by some compilation options. I will bear that in mind, thanks.